# Do Meteor fit this use case, and how many concurrent connections before issues?

Tags: meteor

Say I have an application where for the most part, say 70% of the time, the user experience doesn't need to be real-time, but more like a client-side application making async server requests. The remaining 30% would be spend in turn based "game rooms", each consisting of two users and in which I expect each user to make some kind of action every 4-10 seconds that immediately should be persisted and visible to the other user.

Would Meteor be a good choice for such an application, and if so, how many concurrent users/game-rooms can I expect to support before running into scaling issues with Meteor?

Thanks

Comment: I think this mostly depend on how you implement it and not what framework you choose.

Comment: but theoretically, what is realistic, 100, 1000, 10000s?

Comment: Based on my experience with heroku a 2X dyno should be able to support 100-200 concurrent sessions (in terms of CPU power needed) even if there's mutual dependency between all of them. So if you only need to dependency between two users, then you should probably be able to achieve better results, but I think 1000 would be too optimistic. I think 500 would be the best you can expect.

Comment: is that 500 users in the "gamerooms", or is it all users on the site, including those not using realtime?

Comment: In meteor there's no difference between "real-" and "non-rela-" time. Basically you will have only one type of endpoint and all user connections are handled in more or less the same way. The difference is only in the data you're sending to the users (so subscriptions/publications). Depending on how you design it, it may perform very well or purely. If you can only have two users in a room then it's almost like no dependencies, so the horizontal scaling should be rather trivial.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, it's not how many users are connected at a time, but rather how many messages are sent to how many users at a given point, that dictates the performance?